# How to execute Codeigniter endpoint via CLI when index.php is removed

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I'm using Codeigniter 2. I removed index.php from the URI  to make things simple. My endpoints are working fine and they are in this format

`www.hostapi/users/get`

I've requirement for updating a background process which can update user information in background vi linux command. For this I created an endpoint

`www.hostapi/users/batchUpdates`

This is working fine when i execute through curl. But when i execute via CLI it wont work

`php index.php users batchUpdates`

I even tried with

`php users/bactchUpdates`

I'm unsure how to handle this case since index.php is unavilable

Comment: If you have created your endpoints with the help of the apache configuration, when running from the CLI these won't apply.

Comment: @nigelRen Thanks, is there any work around ?

Comment: have you tried using wget?

Comment: What do you mean by `index.php` is unavailable? It cannot be absent, as it orchestrates all what happens in Codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is:

`php index.php controller method params`

Note there's a blank space between the controller and method names.